# Symfony2 Dependency Injection / Service Container

Tags: class, symfony, service, dependency-injection

I'm pretty new to Symfony2 and have built a custom CMS which has various sections such as user management, page management, image library etc. I want to log all activity within the CMS, therefore thought it would be best to create a centralised class to store the activity so that I can call it from any section.

I've been having a look at dependency injection and service container but struggling to figure out what the difference is? If any?

I've setup the following service but would like feedback on if this is the best method:

```
# app/config/config.yml
# AdminLog Configuration
services:
    admin_log:
        class:        xyz\Bundle\CoreBundle\Service\AdminLogService
        arguments:    [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Below is my class:

```
<?php
namespace xyz\Bundle\CoreBundle\Service;
use xyz\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\AdminLog;

class AdminLogService
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function logActivity($controller, $action, $entityName, $note)
    {
        $adminLog = new AdminLog(
            1,
            $controller,
            $action,
            $entityName,
            $note
        );
        $this->em->persist($adminLog);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

}
```

I will then call this from any controller within the CMS using the following:

```
$this->get('admin_log')->logActivity('Website', 'index', 'Test', 'Note here...');
```

1. Is this the best method?
2. Should the class be inside a 'Service' directory within the bundle as I have done?
3. What is the DependencyInjection folder for?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency Inction means that you pass objects into a class, instead of initializing it in the class. A Service Container is a class which helps you managing all these services (classes which have dependencies).

Your questions:

> Is this the best method?

Yes, except for the namespace.

> Should the class be inside a 'Service' directory within the bundle as I have done?

No, it can live in any namespace. You should put it in a logical namespace, such as `MyBundle\Logger`.

> What is the DependencyInjection folder for?

It's meaned for 3 types of classes: `Extension`, `Configuration` and Compiler passes.

Comment: Services are just normal claasea that are put in a service container. So you should just handle it as normal classes and thus you should put them in a descriptive namespace

Comment: OK can you please give me an example just to confirm? Would xyz\Bundle\CoreBundle\Logger be appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. What would you call the class? Just Admin? AdminLogger? AdminLogLogger? AdminLog is already taken for the Entity class.

Comment: because you are in a namespace, you can just use AdminLog. I would call it an AdminLogger

Comment: Pass classes into a class.. No, pass objects into an object :-) Without a container you can't have DI? That's absolute rubbish! Where do you get this information?

Comment: @Jimbo where did I say you need a container? Something that "helps" is not required, it's just to make someones life easier (DI without container will get complicated quick). And downvoting because of using a wrong word? Oh, I see now. Fixing :) (which you btw can do too by clicking "edit", that's one of the key features of this site, instead of writing a comment indicating what's wrong)

Comment: Before your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16570950/revisions), you stated that without a container you cannot do DI. I'd rather not edit someone's work directly to say *the opposite* of what they've already put. Also, a service container is not a class, it's an object.